# POST request from android to firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, httpurlconnection, google-cloud-functions

I have tried to call my firebase cloud function severally but everything seems to work well except that json parameters cant be accessed `request.body.PARAMETER_NAME` returns undefined always and am stuck at this point.

This is my android code:

```
try {
                      JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                      jsonParam.put("param1", "v1");
                      jsonParam.put("param2", 2302355);
                      jsonParam.put("param3", "v2");

                      URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                      HttpURLConnection connection;
                      connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                      connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", idToken);
                      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                      connection.setUseCaches(false);
                      connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                      connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                      connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                      //Write
                      OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
                      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                      writer.write(jsonParam.toString());
                      writer.close();
                      outputStream.close();
                      ///
                      connection.connect();
                      int res = connection.getResponseCode();
                      a = (res == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
                      if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        server_response = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
                      }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //return (a) ? server_response : "Nothing";
                    return server_response;
```

My server code:

```
exports.SOME_FUNCTION_NAME = functions.https.onRequest(function (request, response) {
if (!request.headers.authorization) {
    console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed');
    response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
}
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(request.headers.authorization).then(function (decodedIdToken) {
    request.user = decodedIdToken;
    response.send(request.body + '\n'+request.params+'\n'+request.data+'\n'+request.headers);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
    response.status(403).send('Unauthorized ' + error);
});
```

});

This is the response I keep getting:

```
[object Object][object Object][undefined][object Object]
```

For `request.body.toJSON`, I get `undefined`as response

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that using request.body.PARAM_NAME works.